# Another word or term to describe 'Not correctly and properly maintain for quite a long time'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was thinking of the word "dysfunction" to describe 'Not correctly and properly maintain for quite a long time' for electrical devices & heavy machinery. However, personally I also feel quite inappropriate to use that word to describe it.

Are there better word(s) or term(s) to describe it?

Comment: We try to avoid using this site for word requests where a thesaurus or other tool would suffice. If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question and let us know what problem you are actually trying to solve. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which word to use, in part, depends on whether you want to indicate only that the devices and machinery have not been properly maintained or also the resulting impaired function.

*Neglected* and *untended*, would describe something not taken care of, as would quite a few synonyms, such as *abandonded*, *overlooked*, or *forgotten*, and one might assume items so described would not be working well.

*Dilapidated* and *[decrepit](http://thesaurus.com/browse/decrepit)*, as well as *ramshackle* and *rickety*, are similar, and would give a stronger suggestion that the item is falling apart or broken down and likely not working well or at all as a result of neglect.

You *could* use [dysfunctional](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dysfunctional), as well as *debilitated*, *crippled*, *impaired*, or *unusable*, but these don't really indicate that the condition is the result of neglect.

Comment: +1 I marked your answer as correct since you have provide far more information that I expected. Good.

Comment: Oh, good. I'm glad you found it useful, because as I was working on this answer, I saw that Gnawme had posted _neglected_, which was my first thought as well, but I always tend toward the more complicated response--not always to the best effect!

Comment: @sarah I went for the quick strike -- which almost worked. Have an upvote to celebrate.

Comment: @Gnawme You have no idea how often this happens to me, specifically with your answers! Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can describe anything that hasn't been properly maintained as *neglected*.

Comment: You beat me to it. +1

Comment: @Mahnax [Your adjective here] minds think alike. :-b

Comment: My adjective is probably *redonkulous*.

Comment: Kidding, of course.

Comment: @Mahnax I like it nonetheless. It's the early leader for Neologism of the Year.

Comment: I work with a very large, serious Punjabi lady with a purple shirt that says "Redonkulous". It makes me want to laugh so very much.

Comment: + Thanks Gnawme for providing such a short single sentence solution.

Answer (score 0):

The word **Dismantled** can be used to describe devices that are disabled and have become useless due to improper maintenance.

Comment: I noted that Dismantled means To take apart; disassemble; tear down; To strip of furnishings or equipment; To strip of covering or clothing. I had another word that just come into my mind while writing this comment - `Break Down` but imo, I don't think it is suitable because I want to emphases that the device become useless / disabled due to incorrect and improperly maintenance.